# Web Service API - Customizing browser.xsl

Tags: rally

How do I use my own custom XSL style sheet with my REST query.  Essentially I want to edit the sample browser.xsl provided by Rally on their Web Service API site.  Do I copy their browser.xsl, edit it and host it somewhere else?

Can I replace the stylesheet parameter in the REST URL with my own xsl URL?

&stylesheet=https://community.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/browser.xsl

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to download and customize/edit:

`/slm/doc/webservice/browser.xsl` and `/slm/doc/webservice/browser.css`

Rally doesn't provide a way to save and reference customized stylesheets on the Rally hosting server, so any customizations you make would need to be hosted somewhere else as you note.

However, as you can see in this Stackoverflow post:

[Fallback strategy for rendering locally downloaded XML files with external XSL stylesheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10411647/fallback-strategy-for-rendering-locally-downloaded-xml-files-with-external-xsl-s)

Many browsers will refuse access to external stylesheets.

You may wish to post an Idea for customization of Rally stylesheets out on [Rally Ideas](http://ideas.rallydev.com) to gain votes and visibility from other Rally users for this as an enhancement.